# Java reading file containing japanese characters

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am trying to read a file which contains some japanese characters.

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("japanese.txt", "r");
String line;
while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
}
```

Its returning some garbled characters instead of japanese.
But when I am converting the encoding, it printing it properly.

```
line = new String(line.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

What does this mean? Is the text file in ISO-8859-1 encoding?

`$ file -i japanese.txt` returns following:

```
japanese.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Please explain which it explicitely requires the file to convert from Latin 1 to UTF-8?

Comment: @RuelosJoel Why is not it taking UTF-8 by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `readString` is an obsolete method, still before charsets/encodings and such. It turns every byte into a char with high byte 0. Byte 0x85 is a line separator (EBCDIC NEL), and if that were in some UTF-8 multibyte sequence, the actual line would be broken into two lines. And some more scenarios are feasible.

Best use [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html). It has a `newBufferedReader(path, Charset)` and a *fixed* default charset UTF-8.

```
Path path = Paths.get("japanese.txt");
try (BufferedReader file = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
    String line;
    while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Now you'll read correct Strings.

A RandomAccessFile basically is for binary data.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is ISO, but I would try reading with that encoding and seeing what happens.

Since you don't do random access, I would just create a BufferedReader with the right encoding and use that:

```
String charSetName = // either UTF-8 or iso - try both
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName(charSetName));
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```